# problem understanding behaviour of subclass python

Tags: python, subclass

I have a class

```
#filename base.py
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def alwaysImport(self):
        raise Exception
```

Inherited file

```
#inherit.py
from base import Base
class Inherit(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def alwaysImport(self):
        # Implemented 
        pass
```

When I am using subclass to check if Inherit is subclass of Base it's showing different behaviour

```
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(inherit.py, path_to_inherit.py)
if spec != None:
    mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
    for name, data in inspect.getmembers(mod, inspect.isclass):
        cls = getattr(mod, name)
        print(name, mod, cls, cls.__bases__)
        if issubclass(cls, Base):
            print("It's true")
```

From my output it's clear that Base is baseclass for Inherit but issubclass is failing

```
Inherit <module 'base' from 'Base.py'> <class 'base.Base'> (<class 'inherit.Inherit'>,)
```

Comment: Did you mean: ‘class Inherit(Base)’ ?

Comment: If `Inherit` is intended to subclass `Base` then it must be declared as `class Inherit (Base)`.

Comment: yes, it is `Inherit(Base)` update question

Comment: @AbhayJain Can you review what your ``spec`` is? Looks like the print statement does not correspond to the output. Expected: name, mod, cls, bases. Got: "Inherit", module base, etc. Expected that the second value is module Inherit.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. I get different output which seems to be correct.